# What are the side effects that happen from high acceleration with brand new car? Does two or three times matter?

Tags: honda, accord, rpm, acceleration

I had a new Honda Accord and I didn't know about break in period that is within the 1000 km, what I did I drove in 120 km/h for two or three times and I made two times acceleration test that reached to 100 km/h. Is that really very harmful or I need to check and how to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Really, there's no way to tell. I'd not worry about it too much and just drive your vehicle normally and perform proper routine maintenance and call it a day. It's funny, though ... new Corvettes have a built in thing in the ECU which doesn't allow the owner to do anything like that until there are enough miles on the vehicle (500 miles, IIRC).

Comment: There is nothing to check. Just drive the car with reasonable speed and gentle acceleration. Modern cars have not needed "breaking in" since before the turn of the century. If you have over-stressed the engine prematurely there is nothing you can do about it anyway. (P.S. if you cannot control your driving urge I suggest taking advanced driving lessons).

Comment: What does your owner's manual say about it? I've read in older manuals that varied speeds are good, and to avoid something like steady cruising at the same speed/rpm for "long periods" (half hour, multiple hours?)